# Why is the input not being written to file even if fprintf is used to pass the input to the file pointer?

Tags: c, io, printf

I was trying some questions based on C and got stuck in this particular problem . Here according to me , old.out file should be written with whatever we take input with scanf as fprintf assigns the input to the file pointer but to my surprise, I saw that nothing is being written to old.out as the later while loop isn't executed . How is this happening ? Has it to do with my misunderstanding of fprintf function ? I have pasted the code below .

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char a;
    fp=fopen("old.out","w");
    if(fp==0)
        printf("File opening error");
    else
    {
        for(scanf("%c",&a);a!=EOF;scanf("%c",&a))
            fprintf(fp,"%c",a);
        fclose(fp);
        fp=fopen("old.out","r");
        while(!feof(fp))
            putchar(getc(fp));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***`int`*** `main()`...

Comment: It's generally considered bad practice to cram complex expressions into your `for` like that...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: yes I too find it annoying but here in India , most of the companies ask such questions in the written rounds of campus interviews . This is also one such question from adobe qualcomm written round. I can do nothing but to prepare such questions if I have to qualify for interview rounds .

Comment: @KavishDwivedi Non sequitur. Why do you have to solve a simple problem using an overly complicated solution?

Comment: @H2CO3: This is actually a question from the written test of Qualcomm . I was just solving one of their papers and I got stuck in this one .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scanf()` doesn't set its argument to `EOF` when it has no more characters to read. So your `for` loop is an infinite loop. Two things to change:

1. Instead of making assumptions, read the documentation.
2. Use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`. (Forget `scanf()`, after all, it doesn't do what you think it does, there are a lot of much better and friendly functions out there, especially for a beginner.)

---

"Okay, okay, but I can haz the codez?"

You can:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[LINE_MAX];
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);

    FILE *fp = fopen("old.out", "w");
    assert(fp);
    fputs(buf, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    fp = fopen("old.out", "r");
    assert(fp);
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp))
        puts(buf);
    fclose(fp); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm yeah fgets and fputs are much better options.

Answer (score 3):

There's quite a lot of problems.

For one, `scanf()` won't *assign* `EOF`, it will *return * `EOF`. Also, `EOF` does not fit in a `char` (it's an `int` value), so `a != EOF` is dangerous. Also, checking `feof()` before doing I/O is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I should have thought about EOF not fitting in char . Ritchie has clearly advised to take int with such situations .